# Lightbox and Rails Only Display First Image in Group

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, lightbox

I just implemented lightbox and was wondering if there was a way to only display the first image in a group?

I have seen it done using hardcode but not dynamically.

I have a model which can have many images and I have them grouping together, but only want to display the first image in the group. Is this possible?

**Each Week Has Many Images (week index)**

```
<% @weeks.each do |week| %>
   <%= render week.creatives %>
<% end %>
```

**partial: _creative.html.erb**

```
 <a href="<%=creative.image.to_s %>" data-lightbox="<%= creative.campaign_id %>"><%= image_tag(creative.image_url(:thumb), class: "img-thumbnail") if creative.image? %></a>
```

Comment: Does `<%= render week.creatives.first %>` do what you need?

Comment: I tried that and essentially it gets the job done esthetically, but when you click on the image, it does not load the rest in the group, only the single image

Comment: @RubyNewbie what exactly you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to show a single image as link and when a user clicks on it then all the images should open up in a popup?

Comment: @user2675613 Correct. The first image is a thumbnail that, when clicked, will display the entire group in that particular collection. I know this can be done when manually coded using the css style "display:none" to all images after the primary, but not sure how to accomplish same result when images are being added dynamically added by the user